# JavaFX with Google Maps - Outstanding resource locks detected: D3D Vram Pool:

Tags: resources, javafx, maps, locks

I'm writing a program that displays Google Map in JavaFX application. Below is a code:

```
public class Window  {

    private static JFXPanel fxContainer;
    MyBrowser myBrowser;
    double lat;
    double lon;
    WindowGPSServer windowsgpsserver;



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                new Window().init();
            }
        });

   }

   public void init() {
      fxContainer = new JFXPanel();
      windowsgpsserver = new WindowGPSServer(fxContainer);
      windowsgpsserver.setVisible(true);

    // create JavaFX scene

      Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
        public void run() {
        //javaFX operations should go here
            createScene();
        }
      });

  }
   private void createScene() {
      myBrowser = new MyBrowser();
      myBrowser.setCache(false);
      Scene scene = new Scene(myBrowser);

      fxContainer.setScene(scene);
      this.windowsgpsserver.setMyBrowser(myBrowser);
  }
 }
```

and:

```
public class MyBrowser extends Pane {
double lat;
double lon;
MyBrowser myBrowser;
WebView webView = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();


    public MyBrowser() {
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();  
        int xSize = ((int) (tk.getScreenSize().getWidth()));  
        int ySize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight()); 
        xSize= new Double(xSize*0.75).intValue();
        ySize= new Double(ySize*0.90).intValue();

        webView.setPrefSize(xSize, ySize);
        final URL urlGoogleMaps = getClass().getResource("demo.html");

        webEngine.load(urlGoogleMaps.toExternalForm());
        webEngine.setOnAlert(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WebEvent<String> e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
                System.out.println(e.getData());
                System.gc();
            }
        });

        getChildren().add(webView);

    }
    public void ChangeLocation(String latit, String longi) {
        lat = Double.parseDouble(latit);
        lon = Double.parseDouble(longi);
        webEngine.executeScript("" +
                    "window.lat = " + lat + ";" +
                    "window.lon = " + lon + ";" +
                    "document.goToLocation(window.lat, window.lon);"
        );
    }     
}
```

and demo.html file:

```
    <body style="height: 100%;" onload="mapaStart()">


    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function mapaStart() {
        //document.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"));
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.857908, 10.598997);
        var Options = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), Options);
        //var carMarkerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('resources/images/car.png');
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(35.857908, 10.598997),
            map: map,
            draggable: false,
    //icon: carMarkerImage,
            title: "",
            autoPan: true

        });
        var infobulle = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "Aktualna pozycja"
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
            infobulle.open(map, marker);
        });


        document.goToLocation = function(x, y) {
            alert("goToLocation, x: " + x +", y:" + y);
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
            marker.setPosition(latLng);
            map.setCenter(latLng);
        }
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
            alert("ZOOM");
        var MapOptions = {
                    scrollwheel: false
            };
        map.setOptions(MapOptions)
            setTimeout(aaa, 1000);

    });

    }
    function aaa() {
            var MapOptions = {
                    scrollwheel: true
            };
        map.setOptions(MapOptions)

    }
    </script>

<div id="mapcanvas" style="width: 100%; height: 90%; border: 1px solid black; background: gray;">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

fxContainer is added to JPanel and displayed in Swing application.
After starting program everything works just fine. But after zooming in and out a couple of times, program becomes unresponsive (hards to zoom, move map to sides) and following error is displayed:

"Outstanding resource locks detected:
D3D Vram Pool: 268 433 488 used (100,0%), 268 433 488 managed (100,0%), 268 435 456 total
39 total resources being managed
average resource age is 0.1 frames
0 resources at maximum supported age (0,000000)
35 resources marked permanent (89,700000)
2 resources have had mismatched locks (5,100000)
2 resources locked (5,100000)
35 resources contain interesting data (89,700000)
0 resources disappeared (0,000000)"

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Thank you

Martin

Comment: Try the latest [Java 8 build](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html), if it's still an issue, [log a bug](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com).

Comment: I'm using latest java8 jdk but it hangs after a short while of zooming in and out. I think it may be something with graphics memory but I have no idea to do.

Comment: My guess is that it is a [known issue](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22D3D%20Vram%20Pool%22%20ORDER%20BY%20updated%20DESC).  Search the links I listed (anybody can create an account and log into the JavaFX issue tracker at the provided link) and if it looks like yours is a duplicate, upvote or comment on the existing issue (which may or may not have workaround instructions), otherwise create a new issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known issue. Could you upvote this https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-36649.

Thanks ! :)